# WiFi card (Atheros AR9565) no longer detected after kernel update

Tags: wireless, atheros, ath9k

Hello everybody out there using Ubuntu,

After upgrading from kernel 4.15.0-192 to version 5.4.0-99 on a ThinkPad X230 with Ubuntu 18.04, the Atheros AR9565 WiFi card of the ThinkPad no longer gets detected.

Comment: What do you mean by "not detected"? Is it shown in `lspci -k` output? And were the `5.5.0-99` is coming from? The current hwe kernel for 18.04 is ` 5.4.0-126`. Did you install the kernel manually? How did you do it?

Comment: Yes, I installed the package for the kernel manually and already found the fix: I also had to install the package `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-99-generic` manually.

Comment: That's the correct fix. But why would you do it this way when you could install `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` and get the latest `5.4` kernel with automatic updates?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS uses the 4.15 kernel if you have GA kernel stack installed; and 5.4 if using the HWE kernel stack; and both kernel stacks can co-exist & be upgraded by the system automatically; however your question implies you didn't install it the documented way (*as everything needed gets installed if that method is used*).  How you added the other stack matters but you gave no details.  Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thanks for your comment with regard to the kernel versions, which is interesting. I experienced troubles probably caused by the display driver when running kernel 4.15.0-192. Therefore, I decided to use a newer kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `lsmod | grep ath9k` as an additional diagnostic and while this command yielded the ath9k module for the older kernel, there was no such module for the newer kernel.

Finally, I found out that this problem can easily be fixed by installing the package `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-99-generic`.